# Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Very Slow (1.5 Mbs)

Tags: networking, wireless

Just finished a new pc build and installed Ubuntu upon booting, version 20.04.

My Wifi adapter is "Panda Wireless PAU09", compatible with 20.04 out of the box.

Here is what `sudo lshw` yields

```
 *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:9
       logical name: wlx9cefd5fbc634
       serial: 9c:ef:d5:fb:c6:34
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=5.4.0-52-generic firmware=0.36 ip=192.168.0.112 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

So far I have:

1. Fixed the bug in Debian Avahi-daemon
2. Disabled wifi power management
3. Tried the `sudo apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms` fix, which yielded

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'backport-iwlwifi-dkms' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdrm2:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfprint-2-tod1 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
  libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
```

Not sure what to do next. In Wifi settings, link speed is listed as 144 Mbs. As for the adapter, there are not any drivers listed on the company website, and for this build version, none seem to exist.

Happy to provide additional details, but please walk me through it if it is not something I could look up how to do as this is my first experience with Ubuntu! haha...

Comment: There seems to be a Realtek card, so `iwlwifi` thing shouldn't be relevant, as it is for Intel. Can you add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 0280` to identify the model.

Comment: The first part of that command yielded a list of information on what I am assuming is the info on my hardware. The part containing "grep" didn't produce anything in the terminal.

Comment: @mikewhatever here is the only listing that I could find that could relate to connectivity. Couldn't see anything related to wireless, but again, I am looking at dozens of lines of output in the terminal, and I have no clue what I'm looking at. <pre>22:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
 Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:7c02]
 Kernel driver in use: r8169
 Kernel modules: r8169
</pre>

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should Edit your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Perhaps it is a USB device, then post the output of `lsusb`. "Panda Wireless PAU09" doesn't tell anything useful about it. Add outputs to the question, not as comments.